# Windows 7 - Explorer.exe constantly building up memory but not releasing it

Tags: windows-7, windows, memory, windows-explorer

I have been trying to figure out the best way to solve this issue with no luck.  We work with a lot of video files, and they are encoded into a folder to be accessed later.  I clear out this folder on a six month rolling basis, but at any given time there are about 500+ videos in this folder.

What is happening is explorer.exe builds up to about 1GB of memory every time this folder is opened.  If we close the explorer window, this memory is not released.  When the folder is opened again, it adds another 1GB of memory on top of the previous.  This usually means that this folder can only be opened about 7 or 8 times before windows practically becomes unusable until restarted or explorer.exe ended and rerun.

I know there are some workarounds like splitting files into a folder or not closing that folder window. Multiple people are encoding videos on this computer a day which means its a little harder to control whats happening on this computer, so I was wondering if this normal behavior, or is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Open `folder option -> View Tab`. Turn on `Always show icons, never thumbnails` option and check if it helps.

Comment: Yea, we never have it showing thumbnails, we need to see the metadata details.

Comment: See if clearing idle processes helps....https://medicine.arizona.edu/helpdesk-article/clear-memory-cache-windows-7

Comment: Clearing the idle processes doesn't seam to help or lower explorer.exe size when no windows are open.

Comment: analyze the memory usage grow with [Windows Performance Toolkit](https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Defrag-Tools/Defrag-Tools-154-Memory-Footprint-and-Leaks#time=16m57s). For Windows 7 use the [Windows 10 TH2/Build 10586 SDK](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/p/?LinkID=698771), newer Win10 SDKs no longer work in Windows 7.